# Black Video outputted via AVMutableVideoComposition and CAAnimation

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, caanimation, avmutablecomposition

I am building iOS application that is able to record video and add animation overlay over recorded video with `AVFoundation` and `CAAnimation`.
All sub features are working fine but end of video's background is black while  animation is playing. It's not rendering background video that I selected. 
I've used `AVAssetWriter` to record video and it's well played on camera roll. But if I use this recorded video to add overlay, end of video's background is black. Interesting thing is if I record video via native iOS camera app and use it to add overlay, it's working perfectly.
I've checked this question but did not work for me. [Black Video CAAnimation and AVFoundation AVAssetExportSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887449/black-video-caanimation-and-avfoundation-avassetexportsession)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to correct preferredTransform of asset, cause for some video files it has empty tx and ty parameters (by default they're 0.0):

```
        ...

        if let clipVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first {
            var preferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform
            var videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.applying(preferredTransform)
            preferredTransform.tx = (videoSize.width < 0) ? fabs(videoSize.width) : 0.0
            preferredTransform.ty = (videoSize.height < 0) ? fabs(videoSize.height) : 0.0
            videoSize = CGSize(width: fabs(videoSize.width), height: fabs(videoSize.height))

            ...

            let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.init(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)
            transformer.setTransform(videoTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

            ...
```